# Can you add more yeast and sugar

Tags: carbonation, stuck-fermentation

I brewed a 6 gallon Mexican ale, it was just after the high krusen phase. The Carboy was in the garage. Temperature outside was between 70&80 degrees. Brought it inside. Put some yeast believe just the regular beer yeast in the Carboy with a cup of sugar. In the room I placed it was the normal brew temperatures. Was any damage done to the Beer?

Comment: Can you clairify the carbonation and stuck-fermentation tags? Are these issues you're having?

Comment: Those two were the only Tags That stuck. Also those are the ones that worries me the most when I brew.

Answer (score 1):

Only "damage" would be from the high temp you had during fermentation. Fusel alcohols, undesirable esters.

Adding more yeast and sugar will only get it fermenting again and raise the ABV up a bit.

Comment: 6 gallon Mexican ale, came off without a hitch. Only thing a little sweet aftertaste. I appreciate everybody's help